# Include of validation.php file does not execute

Tags: php, mysql, validation, post

I have a form (add_company_form.php) in my submit_form_company.php that takes the values from POST and sends them to mysql trough a pdo connection. But I cant get my validation.php to validate the input. I want the user to stay on the same page which is why I dont have a action in the form. The code itself is not complete and there is alot of improvements that can be done, but Im stuck on the validation for now.. Am I on the right track by adding the validation.php before like my db.php?

Submit_form_company.php

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    try {
        include('db.php');
        include('validation.php');

        if(empty($_SESSION["error_message"]) && $_POST['submit_company']) {

            $STH = $conn->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO companies (Name,Notes,OrganizationNumber)
                    VALUES (:Name,:Notes,:OrganizationNumber)");
            $STH->bindParam(':Name', $_POST['Name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $STH->bindParam(':Notes', $_POST['Notes'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $STH->bindParam(':OrganizationNumber', $_POST['OrganizationNumber'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $STH->execute();
        } elseif ($_SESSION["error_message"] && $_POST['submit_edit']) {
            foreach ($_POST['company'] as $i => $value) {
                $STH = $conn->prepare("
                        UPDATE companies
                        SET Name = :Name,Notes = :Notes,OrganizationNumber = :OrganizationNumber
                        WHERE Id = :Id");
                $STH->bindParam(':Id', $value['Id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $STH->bindParam(':Name', $value['Name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $STH->bindParam(':Notes', $value['Notes'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $STH->bindParam(':OrganizationNumber', $value['OrganizationNumber'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $STH->execute();
            }

        }
        if(empty($_SESSION["error_message"])){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        }


    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}

require("add_company_form.php"); 
$DBH = null;
?>
```

add_company_form.php

```
<div class="row">
<form class="col-md-4 navbar-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="Name">Name:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" placeholder="Name"><br />
        <label class="sr-only" for="Notes">Notes:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Notes" placeholder="Notes"><br />
        <label class="sr-only" for="OrganizationNumber">OrganizationNumber:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OrganizationNumber" placeholder="OrganizationNumber"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit_company" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
    <?php
if(!empty($_SESSION["error_message"])){
    echo'<div id="error_message" class="col-md-8">';
    print_alert_error($_SESSION["error_message"]);
    $_SESSION["error_message"] = ""; 
    echo'</div>';   
} ?>-
```

Validation.php

```
<?
$error = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit_company'])) {
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $notes = $_POST['Notes'];
    $organization_number = $_POST['OrganizationNumber'];

    if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(array("'", "-"), "",$name))) { 
        $error .= '<p class="error">Name should be alpha characters only.</p>';
    }

}

//Add error message to session
if (!empty($error)){
    $_SESSION["error_message"] = $error;
}
?>
```

DB.php

```
<?php 
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

?>

Comment: Have you tried debugging by echoing between if-statements to see which steps of code the file reaches?

Comment: Im using xdebug so I can track when it jumps into files, and from what I can see it does not enter the validation.php..

Comment: Does it enter this if-statement: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`?

Comment: Yes it enters all ifs all the way to the execute and enters the db.. But for some reason it does not go into validation.php. I cant figure out what I am missing..

Comment: Does it never reach the first line of `validation.php`? Could you please show the contents of the `db.php` file?

Comment: Thats right, I tried setting the session error value to "test" but it does not even go into that.

Comment: Maybe you could try to remove the `try{}` `catch{}` statements around the code. This would catch all errors instead of displaying them directly. I believe there must be some error which is not shown. You can just comment these out for now and leave only the code inside the `try{}` statement to see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly suggestion but try using the full `<?php` opening tag in your `validation.php` file.

Comment: And there we have it. I knew it was something simple that I was blind to seeing. Thank you.